# Springer document class problem with bibliographystyle

Tags: bibliographies, sv-classes

I am new to springer document class, and I've been trying to add my bib desk file.. It works but I can not add numeric in the style, and it doesn't work as a reference

```
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult} % don't understand what's graybox ?
\usepackage{makeidx} % allows index generation
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\makeindex % used for the subject index % please use the style svind.ist with 
\begin{document}
\title*{Contribution Title} 
\maketitle 
\bibliographystyle{numeric} % it only works with {unsrt} 
\bibliography{/ref.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE as suggested in your previous almost same question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450208/reference-problem-with-svmult-springer-class) instead of repeating your question slightly different.

Comment: \documentclass[graybox]{svmult} % don't understand what's graybox ?
\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style svind.ist with
                       % your makeindex program
\begin{document}
\title*{Contribution Title}
\maketitle

\bibliographystyle{numeric} % it only works with {unsrt}
\bibliography{/ref.bib}

\end{document}

Comment: @faltfe
Thanks for your answer, I hope you can figure out what's wrong... and sorry for not providing the MWE.. as I am still writing the .tex file

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{numeric}` does not make sense, as there is no `numeric.bst` style file. Use `\bibliographystyle{plain}` (or another existing bib style).

Comment: @egreg   
thanks for your prompt reply. I do understand, plain works fine but not in a numeric order I mean not 1 then 2... it works randomly. In addition, how can I insert numeric.bst... 
Finally, would you mind telling me, which existing bib style should work..

Comment: If by “numeric” you mean “in order of appearance”, then `\bibliographystyle[unsrt}` should be what you need.

Comment: @egreg 
Thanks again, yeah it works in order of appearance, but if you click on the reference, you will not get to the reference in the last page ?

Comment: @Refat_Gir Please, make a small example of code that shows the issue. But add it to the question, not in comments.

Comment: @egreg.. I've edited the question, so please have a look, I have been trying with hypref command, but I do not wanna them highlighted

Comment: @egreg.. I have tried now with \usepackage{hyperref}
but it isn't being worked unfortunately